# System properties difference between jetty-maven-plugin and jetty-runner

Tags: docker, jetty

I have been using the jetty-maven-plugin to successfully run my api from eclipse and it does substitute the system properties.

My Jetty file is below

```
 <New id="pdsDatasourcePool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
<Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
<Arg>jdbc/ads</Arg>
<Arg>
  <Call class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory" name="getPoolDataSource" >
    <Set name="URL"><SystemProperty name="DB.URL" /></Set>
    <Set name="user"><SystemProperty name="DB.USERNAME" /></Set>
    <Set name="password"><SystemProperty name="DB.PASSWORD" /></Set>
    <Set name="minPoolSize"><SystemProperty name="DB_CONNECTION_MIN_POOL_SIZE" type="Integer" default="2" /></Set>
    <Set name="maxPoolSize"><SystemProperty name="DB_CONNECTION_MAX_POOL_SIZE" type="Integer" default="10"/></Set>
    <Set name="initialPoolSize"><SystemProperty name="DB_CONNECTION_INITIAL_POOL_SIZE" type="Integer" default="2"/></Set>
    <Set name="connectionFactoryClassName">oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl</Set>
  </Call>
</Arg>
```

These properties get substituted by the correct values when I use -D for the property/values.

However, when we do the actual deployment we use jetty-runner in a Docker container and unless I hardcode the values, the application does not run. I tried using -e to get the values to be substituted but it does not work.

Inside the container, the start script is shown below

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE \
-Dlogback.configurationFile=opt/config/logback.xml -Dlogs.output=/opt/logs -Dlogs.loglevel=ERROR \
 -Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger \
 -jar /opt/jetty-runner.jar \
 --port 8082 --stats unsecure \
 --config /opt/config/jetty/jetty.xml --config /opt/config/env/jetty-http-env.xml \
 --lib /opt/lib \
 /opt/event-microservice-api.war /opt/event-microservice-listener.war
```

My question is there a specific way in which parameters should be substituted when using jetty-runner?

Cheers
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update "SystemProperty" to "Env" as below. This will work.

```
<Set name="URL"><Env name="DB_URL"/></Set>
<Set name="user"><Env name="DB_USERNAME"/></Set>
<Set name="password"><Env name="DB_PASSWORD"/></Set>
<Set name="minPoolSize"><Env name="DB_CONNECTION_MIN_POOL_SIZE" type="Integer" default="2" /></Set>
<Set name="maxPoolSize"><Env name="DB_CONNECTION_MAX_POOL_SIZE" type="Integer" default="10"/></Set>
<Set name="initialPoolSize"><Env name="DB_CONNECTION_INITIAL_POOL_SIZE" type="Integer" default="2"/></Set>
```